# Get css background image (set with html attribute 'style') with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an html div, with the class `.photoBackground` and an id `#photo`. The id is the one, having all the background image options, height width etc. The background image itself is in the in div attribute `style="background-image:url(link.jpg)"`. This is a gallery, where all the divs are exact the same, except 1 which use `#photo2`, because i need a slightly different setting. Anyway, i need to get the url from style attribute. How do i do that?

HTML:

```html
        <div id="lightbox_shadow_container">
            <a id="lightbox-shadow"></a>
            <div id="lightboxCancelCross_container">
                <svg class="lightboxCancelCross" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="35px" height="35px" viewBox="0 0 612 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 612;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g id="cross">
  <g>
   <polygon points="612,36.004 576.521,0.603 306,270.608 35.478,0.603 0,36.004 270.522,306.011 0,575.997 35.478,611.397 
    306,341.411 576.521,611.397 612,575.997 341.459,306.011    "/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
            </div>
            <div id="lightbox_caption_container">
                <a id="lightbox"></a>
                <div class="photoCaptionEffect">
                    <p class="photoCaptionBig" style="               
    "></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="photoBackground" id="photo" style="background-image: url(Styling-Content/galleriBilleder/image11.JPG);">
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photoBackground').on('click',function () {
        var idIClickedOn = '#' + $(this).attr('id'); //this will give you the actual id of the element
        var image = $(idIClickedOn ).css('background-image');
        // remove "url(" and ")" to get the url
        image = image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        $("#lightbox").css('background-image','url(' + image + ')');
        var captionOG = $(this).find('p.photoCaption'); $(".photoCaptionBig").text($(captionOG).text().replace(captionOG, "photoCaptionBig")); 
        $('#lightbox_shadow_container').show();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').show();
        $('#lightbox').show();
    });
    $('#lightbox-shadow').click(function() {
        $('#lightbox').hide();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').hide();
        $('#lightbox_shadow_container').hide();
        $('#lightbox').css("background-color", "");
        
    });
    $(".lightboxCancelCross").click(function(){
        $("#lightbox-shadow").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: put your html code here with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to get the url from style attribute

Try utilizing `.css("backgroundImage")` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/url\(|\)/g`

```js
var url = $("div").css("backgroundImage").replace(/url\(|\)/g, "");
console.log(url)
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats)"></div>
```

---

If requirement is to use full value of `.css("backgroundImage")` , `.replace()` not needed ; additionally could substitute `$(this)` for `var idIClickedOn = '#' + $(this).attr('id')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photoBackground').on('click',function () {
        // var idIClickedOn = '#' + $(this).attr('id'); //this will give you the actual id of the element
        var image = $(this ).css('background-image');
        // remove "url(" and ")" to get the url
        // image = image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        $("#lightbox").css('background-image', image).show();
        // var captionOG = $(this).find('p.photoCaption'); $(".photoCaptionBig").text($(captionOG).text().replace(captionOG, "photoCaptionBig")); 
        // $('#lightbox_shadow_container').show();
        // $('#lightbox-shadow').show();
        // $('#lightbox').show();
    });
  /*
    $('#lightbox-shadow').click(function() {
        $('#lightbox').hide();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').hide();
        $('#lightbox_shadow_container').hide();
        $('#lightbox').css("background-color", "");
        
    });
    $(".lightboxCancelCross").click(function(){
        $("#lightbox-shadow").trigger("click");
    });
    */
});
```

```css
#lightbox {
  display:none;
}

#lightbox, .photoBackground {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="photoBackground" id="photo" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats);"></div>
  <div id="lightbox"></div>
```

Comment: What i want, is that i wanna copy the url and place it somewhere else.Not change it, as your code suggest! :)

Comment: If expected result is full string `url(/path/to/image/)` , try removing `.replace()` at close of `.css("backgroundImage")` , as described at either solution posted

Comment: i'm not sure its working, because i already have it. Since there is a lot of images, identical setups,it just loads the first images of the list. Hmm.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard _"i'm not sure its working, because i already have it. Since there is a lot of images, identical setups,it just loads the first images of the list. Hmm. "_ Can include `html` at Question ? Tried iterating elements utilizing `.each()` , to extract `backgroundImage` value for each element ?

Comment: i have this:     
$('.photoBackground').on('click',function () {
        var idIClickedOn = '#' + $(this).attr('id'); //this will give you the actual id of the element
        var image = $(idIClickedOn ).css('background-image');
        // remove "url(" and ")" to get the url
        image = image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        $("#lightbox").css('background-image','url(' + image + ')');

Comment: That's old code, but since i change the idea forming unique, to be identical it doesn't work

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard _"That's old code, but since i change the idea forming unique, to be identical it doesn't work – "_ ? Appear opposite of first comment _"What i want, is that i wanna copy the url and place it somewhere else.Not change it, as your code suggest! :)"_ ? Can include `html` , `js` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Already done check OP, i need to copy each url when clicked, to create a lightbox. The lightbox have worked before, when the html id was unique, but stopped working, when they now are identical.

Comment: Wouldmit be possible to use each? Lightbox is not inside the div, but somewhere on top. :)

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard `#lightbox` is single element , `.each()` not appear necessary

Comment: _"why did you draw out my old code?"_ `html` not included at Question ? , not appear portion of Question ?

Comment: explain your code then, i dont get it. I added lightbox to question.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard At click of `.photoBackground` element set `#lightbox` element `backgroundImage` to `.photoBackground' element `backgroundImage`

Answer (score 0):

You use the jQuery element's css method

```
$("#myID").css('background-image')
```

where myID is the ID of the div (you can use any other selector by the way)